# Will I lose the pages I've created within a default WordPress theme when adding a new theme?

Tags: themes

Will I lose the pages I've created within the default WordPress theme when adding a new theme, or will a new theme accommodate the same structure and content already created? I'm new to WordPress and can't find the answer on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress is a content management system.  Your content is saved in a database and is independent of whatever theme you choose to use to display that content.  So, short answer: no.